# How to deactivate click event on Unity Slider UI?

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine, slider

In Unity, I would like to use the slider in my canvas but only the handle.

A default behaviour is that if the user clicks on a certain point in the slider , the handle will jump right to that point. I would like to disable this behaviour, allowing the user only to drag the handle to move it.

How can this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply uncheck the *Raycast Target* property of the **Image** component located on the *Background* **GameObject**.

Otherwise you could always override the **Slider** class to fit your need but i guess this would be a bit overkill in your case.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Disable interactable checkbox in inspector. This option added with new versions.